# How to pass a custom callback function onSubmit in Formik with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, callback, formik

I am trying to pass a custom callback function after a succesfull form is completed. When I try to pass my callback function, `handleCount` to onSubmit, Formik doesn't seem to pass this to my parent React component.

**Note**:
My previous approach that worked was to add onSubmit to the button: `<button onSubmit={handleCount}>...</button>`, but this will pass handleCount when the form still has errors.

Here is my code and architecture:

```js
// Join.js
export default function Join({handleCount} {
  <Formik
  ...
  onSubmit={async (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
    handleCount
    await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 500));
    setSubmitting(false);
  }}
}

<button type="submit">CREATE ACCOUNT</button>
```

```js
//Signup.js
import Join from "../components/SignUpFlow/1-SignUp/Join";
 
<Join handleCount={handleCount}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it work by passing the setSubmitting function as a function instead of part of an object.  The following code worked for me:

```
// Join.js
export default function Join({ handleCount }) {
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ email: "", password: "" }}
      validate={(values) => {
        const errors = {};
        if (!values.email) {
          errors.email = "Required";
        } else if (
          !/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i.test(values.email)
        ) {
          errors.email = "Invalid email address";
        }
        return errors;
      }}
      onSubmit={async (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log("called");
          alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
          setSubmitting(false);
        }, 400);
      }}
    >
      {({
        values,
        errors,
        touched,
        handleChange,
        handleBlur,
        isSubmitting,
      }) => (
        <form
          onSubmit={async (values, setSubmitting) => {
            handleCount();
            await new Promise((response) => setTimeout(response, 500));
            setSubmitting(false);
          }}
        >
          <input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            value={values.email}
          />
          {errors.email && touched.email && errors.email}
          <input
            type="password"
            name="password"
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            value={values.password}
          />
          {errors.password && touched.password && errors.password}
          <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
            CREATE ACCOUNT
          </button>
        </form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
}

    // Signup.js
  function App() {
      function handleCount() {
        console.log("function handleCount called.");
      }
    
      return <Join handleCount={handleCount} />;
    }
```